# When you mouseover an opened app icon on the task bar, a screenshot preview is shown, is it possible to modify it?

Tags: c#, windows, taskbar

The problem:

- when you have multiple windows from the same app opened across multiple screens (monitors), it can be hard to track which one is in which screen without having to hover over each one of them to get a little preview.

The solution:

- something like this: would be perfect:
  [image]

and the user had for example 5 chrome windows opened, 3 of them are opened in Monitor-1, then when hovering over the task bar icon, the user would see [2] [3] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVa3l.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVa3l.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVa3l.png).

- The order would follow the current Windows OS logic (sorted by which window is opened first) but it would be nice to actually re-arrange them by Screen order, so the previous example would be [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVa3l.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVa3l.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVa3l.png) [2] [3]

Is this possible ?

Thanks a lot!